# Custom CSS for page tab WordPress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a WordPress site with a tabbed page in the user's profile. There are two tabs:

```
User Info
Categories
```

I need to add custom styling to the Categories tab but the only difference I can find in the HTML markup is this:

```
data-anchor="categories"
```

I thought I could use that in my CSS but every attempt I've made to get this working has failed. These are two attempts I have made and both of them fail.

```
.sow-tabs-tab [data-anchor="categories"]
.sow-tabs-tab div[data-anchor="categories"]
```

Here's the HTML for this one tab:

```
<div class="sow-tabs-tab sow-tabs-tab-selected" role="tab" data-anchor="categories">
```

And here's the HTML for the User Info tab:

```
<div class="sow-tabs-tab" role="tab" data-anchor="user-info">
```

Is there any way to use the data-anchor value in my CSS to accomplish this goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the space between the class name and the attribute. The other line of CSS doesn't make much sense to me looking at the HTML samples.

```css
.sow-tabs-tab[data-anchor="categories"] {
margin-top: 5rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="sow-tabs-tab sow-tabs-tab-selected" role="tab" data-anchor="categories">Category</div>
```

Comment: ok i'll run that today and see what happens. the second line i put in my post was just a variation i tried in CSS to see if it would work. i'll edit my post to clarify that point.